# Have a trouble with developing an app for smarteyeglass

Tags: android, sony-smarteyeglass

Recently,i need to build an app for smart eyeglass. with official instruction,i have to import three library project,including SmartExtensionAPI,SmartExtensionUtils SmartEyeglassAPI.and i have develop dependencies for my project when i run this app, there a lot of error information.

> such as Error:(44, 57)
>   com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.notification is not
>   existing;Error:(45, 57)
>   com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.registration is not
>   existiong!Error:(49, 52)com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.control
>   is not existing,Error:(198, 40)Registration.Intents is not existing
>   and so on.

what's wrong? search for help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing registration for your extension in your application.

Please take a look at sample projects for details. You can also start developing directly using sample projects in the SDK.

Comment: thank for your answer.I had solved this questions.The problem is dependency relationship。